# Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, cpanel

Tengo un detalle al clonar más de un repositorio de Github en mi CPanel por medio de SSH. Generé un archivo "config" dentro de la carpeta .ssh con la siguiente configuración:

```
    Host github-sitio
       HostName github.com
       User git
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
       
    Host github-pacientes
       HostName github.com
       User git
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pacientes
```

En dicho código hago referencia a dos llaves SSH creadas por terminal y también ya están asignadas en los repositorios correspondientes. El problema es que no puedo clonar el segundo repositorio (*pacientes*), hice los mismos pasos para generar las llaves en ambos.
El error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si me esté haciendo falta algún detalle.

Comment: Hola. El mensaje de error es claro: o la URL de ese repositorio está mal, o las credenciales que usas no son correctas. Revisa ambas cosas, no podemos revisarlo por ti.

Comment: Para la creación de las llaves no utilicé contraseña y fueron asignadas en su repositorio correspondiente. Solo el primer repositorio (sitio) sí lo clona, el segundo no. Igual voy a ver si me faltó algo para el segundo repositorio

Comment: No sé cómo estás pasando la URL del repositorio, debes verificar eso, y procura pasarle la URL obtenida activando la pestaña **`SSH`**, la que tiene el formato: `git@github.com:elUsuario/elRepositorio.git`, porque si le pasas `https` puede que no funcione.

Comment: Cierto fue un dato que no puse, pero sí hago la clonación con **SSH** para los dos repositorios, posiblemente sea algo que no estoy viendo en mi segundo repositorio que en el primero sí hice. Estaré revisando.

Comment: El mensaje de error te lo está diciendo claro: o el repositorio está mal escrito y por eso no lo encuentra, o registraste mal las credenciales. Ambas cosas debes verificarlas. Si el repo está en Github, puedes verificar también allí las claves que tienes activas y verificar que efectivamente pusiste esas claves en tu servidor.

Comment: Cual es la dirección del remoto que estás usando (como la pusiste en git)?

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano